# Replace multiple elements in a list with a single element

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to replace two or more elements with a single element in a list like this:

```
mylist=['a','b','c']
```

Now I want to replace 'a' and 'b' elements with another element 'z'.
So output should be:

```
['z','z','c']
```

Comment: `["z" if x in ("a", "b") else x for x in mylist]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a list-comprehension an option:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new_list = [x if x not in "ab" else "z" for x in mylist]
print(new_list)  # ['z', 'z', 'c']
```

if the elements you want to replace are more complicated you could try:

```
if x not in {"a", "b"}
```

---

if you want to change things based on the index `i` you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
new_list = [x if i >= 2 else "z" for i, x in enumerate(mylist)]
print(new_list)  # ['z', 'z', 'c']
```

but then you could consider [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=slice#sequence-types-list-tuple-range):

```
new_list = 2 * ["z"] + mylist[2:]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but i was wondering if there was a method to use indices of the list. Like mylist[0] and mylist[1] to replace 'a' and 'b'. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes but I don't like the `if i >= 2` part much because what if the list is bigger? Let's say it contains 10 elements and i want to replace first, third, and seventh element for example? I can't do that this way. Do you know any other solutions?

Comment: Thanks I feel dumb